# RuntimeError: run loop already started in pyttsx

Tags: python-2.7, runloop, pyttsx

I am creating a DIY virtual assistant for fun and exercise in python. I run into a problem when trying to use engine.say in a thread and then use it again in my main program.

I already tried to use engine.endLoop() and other possible solutions from pyttsx docs (engine.stop(),  engine.endLoop() etc) but still i didn't make it work. I have seen in some answers about asyncio. But with pip i can't install it and i am not very certain that it will solve my problem.

The Functions:

```
def portport():

        ser = serial.Serial('COM4',9600)
        raw_data = ser.read(9)
        msg = str(raw_data[3:8])
        print msg
        ser.close()
        return msg

def Comm_Connection():

    print("CommConns started")

    while True:
        global conn

        try:
            conn, addr = SERVER.accept()
            Live_Conns.append(conn)

            Server_Send = "Connection established successfully"
            Server_Send = pickle.dumps(Server_Send)
            Live_Conns[-1].send(Server_Send)

            temp = conn.recv(1024)
            Server_Receive = pickle.loads(temp)

            Live_Name.append(Server_Receive)

            Connections = (Live_Name[-1], "Connected")

            engine.say(Connections)
            engine.runAndWait()

        except socket.error as socketerror:
            continue
        except socket.timeout:
            continue
```

The "Main" program:

```
Server_Up = threading.Thread(target = Comm_Connection)
Server_Up.start()

while True:  
    engine = pyttsx.init()  

    time.sleep(7)
    engine.say("Goodmorning")
    engine.runAndWait()
```

And the error i get:

raise RuntimeError('run loop already started')

RuntimeError: run loop already started

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `while True` loop is trying to start and run the pyttsx engine at the same time it's being operated inside the `Comm_Connection` loop.

Note that pyttsx uses its own internal engine that supports callbacks and manual iteration, so you might consider rewriting your app more along the lines of the following [example modified from the docs](https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html#examples):

```
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.', 'fox')
engine.startLoop(False)
# engine.iterate() must be called inside Server_Up.start()
Server_Up = threading.Thread(target = Comm_Connection)
Server_Up.start()
engine.endLoop()
```

Disclaimer: I've played around enough with this library to know that the manual iteration approach does work, but not enough to understand your particular needs, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a common question and I figured out a solution for this for my program. To use a private variable to judge if the loop is already started and then end it if it is using `engine._inLoop` -

```
while True:  
    engine = pyttsx.init()  

    time.sleep(7)
    engine.say("Goodmorning")
    engine.runAndWait() 

    if engine._inLoop:
        engine.endLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all install pyttsx3 with `pip uninstall pyttsx` `pip install pyttsx3` and then try this

```
while True:  
    engine = pyttsx3.init()  

    time.sleep(7)
    engine.say("Goodmorning")
    engine.runAndWait() 
    engine = None
```

you are defining `engine = pyttsx.init()`in the loop every time
so it will say that the loop is already started
but if you define `engine = None` for every iteration it will work at least it did for me